# dynamically generated link not displaying in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a dot net page that shows/hides panels.  when I set compatibility view "display all websites in Compatibility View" the Last panels dynamically generated link does not display but it does exist. I can click on it and the panel is hidden.

If I check Only the IE Compatibility View box "Display intranet sites in Compatibility view" then the last panels "Hide Details" link displays and works fine.

I'm only going to post the JavaScript as it should be sufficient for this question. The markup simply has an inline call to the JS TogglePanel method. The inline call is dynamically generated with unique ClientIDs for each panel and for each link

Any clues as to what the heck is going on here will be greatly appreciated!!

NOTE: This JS script works perfectly.

```
    function TogglePanel(panel, link) {
        var selectedPanel = $("." + panel);
        var selectedLink = $(link);
        if (selectedPanel.is(":visible")) {
            selectedPanel.hide();
            selectedLink.text('Show Details');
        }
        else {
            selectedPanel.show();
            selectedLink.text('Hide Details');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're using jQuery 2.x which does not support IE compatibility mode, even with IE10.  So, if you force the page into compatibility mode, then it will not work with jQuery 2.x in IE 10.  If the page can be in standards mode, not compatibility mode, then it will work with jQuery 2.x.

Of, if you use jQuery 1.9, it will work with either mode.

Another possibility is that you have some sort of invalid HTML that only causes a problem in one particular mode.